# change API 19 to 18 ? Xamarin Studio

Tags: android, xamarin

i tried to develop *application* for android but my device not 
support API 19 how can i change the API **to** 16 ?
have any solution for that problem .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two project options that you may want to change: **Target Framework** and **Minimum Android Version**.

The **Target Framework** determines which version of Android your application is compiled against.

The **Minimum Android Version** determines the lowest version of Android your application can be installed on.

The simplest fix would be to change the project's Target Framework to target the API level that your device runs on. By default the Mininum Android Version is set to be the same as the Target Framework.

Target Framework can be found in the project options by right clicking the project in the **Solution** window, selecting **Options**, then in the **General** category selecting **Build**. Then you can change the Target Framework to be the one you want - Android 4.1 (API 16) or Android 4.3 (API 18).

The Minimum Android Version can be changed in project options in the **General** section by selecting the **Android Application** category. Then there is a Minimum Android Version drop down you can select.

If you select a minimum Android version lower than your Target Framework then your code will need to handle certain APIs not being available at lower Android versions. So at runtime you would need to check the Android.OS.Build.Version.SdkInt and not call an API if it is not available on the current Android version.

Comment: thanks one other things i was install in my PC xamiren and now expired !! and i choose free virson !

Comment: When I open my project options, there is not "Build" in the "General" category (but there is one outside), and I can't even find the phrases "Target Framework" or "Minimum Android Version" anywhere at all in the Solution Options.

Comment: @BeritLarsen - Not sure what the problem is. At a guess you may have right clicked the solution and selected Options. That will show you the solution options. If you right click the Android project and select Options that should give you the project options. If your dialog says Solution Options then you have opened the wrong dialog.

Comment: Any idea how visual studio populates that list? The API Level I want to support isn't listed

Answer (score 0):

***you would find minSdkVersion/targetSdkVersion in the build.gradle (module:app)file under the Gradle Scripts Directory. Edit the build version here and then open the Manifest file to  Synch the changes made.***

Comment: the OP is talking about Xamarin, not native android